# Cannot append x with reverse(x): Type mismatch: expected Node, List<Node> or List<List<Node>> but was List<Any>

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I attempted to perform

```
RETURN nodes(path1) + reverse(nodes(path2))
```

which caused this error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Node, List<Node> or List<List<Node>> but was List<Any>
```

Here is a minimal example:

**Input:**

```
WITH range(1, 3) AS xs
RETURN xs + reverse(xs)
```

**Expected result:** [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]

**Actual result:**

```
Type mismatch: expected Integer, List<Integer> or List<List<Integer>> but was List<Any> (line 2, column 13 (offset: 35))
"return xs + reverse(xs)"
             ^
```

Instead, I must use this workaround:

```
WITH range(1, 3) AS xs
RETURN xs + [i IN range(size(xs) - 1, 0, -1) | xs[i]]
```

I believe reverse(xs) should have the same element type as xs itself, but instead its type is erased to "Any". Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

(You should probably create a new [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for this unexpected `reverse()` behavior.)

As a workaround to your original problem, you can reverse the match pattern that you used to get `path2`, so that NODES(path2) would already be "reversed", which would eliminate the need to use the `reverse()` function at all.

For example, if you currently have:

```
MATCH path2=(:Person {id: 1})-[:LIKES]->(:Cat {id: 2})
```

you can do this instead:

```
MATCH path2=(:Cat {id: 2})<-[:LIKES]-(:Person {id: 1})
```